# relationship between $\operatorname{diff}(f)$ and $d(f)$

Tags: derivatives

I have a series $x$ and a function $f(x)$ and I need to calculate the scalar differences $\operatorname{diff}(f(x))$.

Having both $x$ and the function $f$ available, I can simply replace $x$ in $f$ and obtain
the data I need.
But wanting to use the analytic function of the derivative $d(x)(f)$
which
relationship exists between $\operatorname{diff}(f(x))$ and $d(x)(f)$?

Or should I use a different derivative function?

The important thing that interests me is that I don't have to move on the $x$-axis for the calculation

as is the case with $\operatorname{diff}(f(x_i) - f(x_i-1))$.

So for each $x_i$ I obtain $d(x)(f(x_i))$ using only $x_i$.

Basically I'm asking for the inverse relation of the finite difference method. In my case I want to calculate the approximation of finite differences given the derivative function. The step of the differences is not known but I have the differences of $x$ available to compute the differences of $f(x)$ using the derivative of $f$.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a specific computer algebra system?

Comment: yes , but I must solve it algebrically first !